# "A Crackpot Idea" - як перекласти українською?

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

Чи існує прямий український відповідник до англ. **[a crackpot / a crackpot idea](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crackpot)** або інший еквівалент до цієї фрази, доцільний до вжитку в українській мові?

Чи буде правильним такий переклад: **божевільна ідея**?

Comment: Ви хочете, щоб обов'язково було присутнє слово ідея/думка/задум? Якщо ні, то нісенітниця/маячня/казна-що/чортибатька-що і багато інших подібних.

Comment: А якщо перекладати "crackpot" як прикметник?

Comment: химерна/дивакувата/крива/навіжена/схибнута ідея?